# link to automatically open my App?

Tags: iphone

1) Is it possible for an iPhone (iOS device) to automatically open an App (that they already have installed) when the user taps on a link (for example a link they received via email)?  I'm thinking of using emails for notifications and all the email would have is some text about the notification and then a link that would automatically open the App - it doesn't have to pass any data to the App.  If this is possible, sample code (or a URL that explains this) would be much appreciated.

2) In addition, if the user did not have the App, it would be nice if the link could open up the App Store directly to my App so they could download/purchase.

Thanks in advance.

BCB

Comment: Thanks everyone, both answers were accurate - I actually figured this out before seeing the answers here.  My biggest issue was figuring out how to get email clients (specifically gmail) to not strip out HTML codes it didn't recognize so the link would be clicksble.  For example, I tried putting <a HREF = "myapp:\\">click here</a> but gmail would strip it.  Finally ended up including a http link to my server with an auto redirect, which worked.

Comment: So your redirect on your server pointed to your URL scheme?

Comment: Without including the server here, is it not possible to open app from Apple mail app(user tap on link from mail)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add an URL scheme to your application in the info plist file.

Then catch this in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation`
Read this [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) about the URL scheme I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link to this very specific tutorial.

Comment: The link appears dead. [Here's the Wayback machine version.](http://web.archive.org/web/20160103151535/http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Answer (score 6):

1) Yes you can do what you described. See the **Implementing Custom URL Schemes** section in the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html)

2) I don't think you can do that. But you could provide a message to the user with another link to the AppStore. Have a look at the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help, if i could select two answers as "accepted answers" I would.  Terente Alex's link had a very specific tutorial which was extremely helpful.