# How to Create Hyperlink to Open iPhone/iPad App?

Tags: iphone, ipad, hyperlink

I would like to create a hyperlink that when clicked, it will open an iPhone/iPad application.

Forgive me if this post is already out in the database, but I could not find it. I am not the developer for application, but I need have a link that I can send in email or leave in Google Docs (for example), that when clicked, the app will open.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I accomplish this? I understand I may be over my head as I am not a developer of any sorts; just wondering if there was an easy way to do this, or if there is a free website out there that can generate this for me.

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [link to automatically open my App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462612/link-to-automatically-open-my-app)

Comment: The app needs to register for specific URL types, your can't do it after development, it's a feature that needs to be implemented while developing the app.